# Python 3-Returning a recursive value from a choice option and

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a touch of difficulty in getting my values to display using recursive methods. I am wanting to type in 10 numbers and, depending on the choice, will return the largest number, the smallest number, and the sum of the numbers. I am getting two errors: One is that the (len) cannot return an int and if I put in a value in the individual function, it will continue to loop until the program reaches it's parsing limit (999). I am not sure how to proceed and get the values I want and it seems to be a main issue with the values I put in. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
def displayMenu():
    print('Enter 1 to find the largest number: ')
    print('Enter 2 to find the smallest number: ')
    print('Enter 3 to sum the list of numbers: ')
    print('Enter 4 to exit: ')

choice = int(input('Please enter your choice: '))

while choice <= 0 or choice >= 5:
    print('Enter 1 to find the largest number: ')
    print('Enter 2 to find the smallest number: ')
    print('Enter 3 to sum the list of numbers: ')
    print('Enter 4 to exit: ')
    choice = int(input('Please enter your choice: '))
else:
    return choice

def main():
    MIN = 1
    MAX = 100
    num_MAX = 10
    user_num = []
    number_list = []
    for i in range(num_MAX):
        user_num = int(input('Please enter a number at this time: '))
    while user_num < 1 or user_num > 100:
        user_num = int(input('Please re-enter numbers between 1 and 100:' ))
        number_list.append(user_num)
    choice = displayMenu()
    while choice != 4:
        if choice == 1:
            largest = find_largest(user_num)
            print('The largest number is: ', largest)
        elif choice == 2:
            smallest = find_smallest(user_num)
            print('The smallest number is: ', smallest)
        elif choice == 3:
            summy = find_sum(user_num)
            print('The sum of the numbers entered is: ', summy)

        choice = displayMenu()

def find_largest(user_num):
    n = len(user_num)
    if n == 1:
        return user_num[0]
    else:
        temp = find_largest(user_num[0:n - 1])
    if user_num[n - 1] > temp:
        return user_num[n - 1]
    else:
        return temp
def find_smallest(user_num):
    n = len(user_num)
    if n == 1:
        return user_num [0]
    else:
        temp = find_smallest(user_num[0:n - 1])
    if user_num[n - 1] < temp:
        return user_num[n - 1]
    else:
        return temp
def find_sum(user_num):
    user_num = [1,2,3,4]
    n = len(user_num)
    if len(user_num) == 1:
        return user_num [0]
    else:
        return user_num[n - 1] + sum[0:n - 1]

main()
```

Comment: Looks like homework! Firstly, is there a reason why you want/need to use recursion for this? It's not a particularly simple or efficient means of finding the largest number in an array!

Comment: Also, please note the code you have provided does not compile (bad indentation). Also, the reason you get that error is that you are passing the wrong value to your functions. You meant to pass `number_list` not `user_num`. But the problems go far beyond that.

Comment: No, not for homework--it's a launch program and I haven't used python very much. The folks want us to learn recursion for their crawler program.

Comment: Also thank you for your help, it was just what I needed! I managed to replace user_num and changed it to a different value all together. I now know what you mean saying the problems were far beyond that. I did quite a few revisions and main things were trying to sum a string using recursive. Thanks again, I appreciate it!